# Laravel API token authentication vs web Route::prefix('api')

Tags: php, laravel, api, token

I'm wondering what is a better practice using the API with a token or the web router with a prefix:
Have a token that changes every time a user logs in. API:

```
Route::get('userdata/{key}', 'userController@show');
```

vs

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
Route::get('userdata', 'userController@show');
});
```

In the web router I can use cookies to verify an user.

Which of these is better?

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to use any 'key' or something fields in route/body to get data for logged / session user. You can create static route for get 'self-data' and fetch current user data according header (bearer or something other auth) or cookies.

```
Route::get('userdata', 'userController@show');
```

with cookies/header will be ok. Also don`t forget to use auth middleware, where you should validate cookies/header.

Answer (score 0):

Group all the api routes and apply your custom middleware that will check for the bearer token in request headers. Here is how to do it:

**Create a middleware:**

```
class AuthenticateWithToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $request->bearerToken();
        if ($token==='valid') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

**Register your middleware in App\Http\Kernel.php:**

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'authenticateWithToken' => AuthenticateWithToken::class
    ];
}
```

**Apply middleware on routes:**

```
Route::middleware('authenticateWithToken')
    ->prefix('api')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/route1', 'YourController@action1');
        Route::get('/route2', 'YourController@action2');
    });
```